# PRIMARY index not used if too few entries

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.7

this query :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT cmd.cmd_date, liv.liv_nom
FROM cmd
    LEFT JOIN liv USE INDEX(PRIMARY) ON cmd.liv_id = liv.liv_id
WHERE 1
ORDER BY cmd_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

gives me a different result when the table liv contains 5 or 6 rows.

6 rows :

```
1   SIMPLE  cmd     ALL                 134331  100 Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  l       eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   cmd.liv_id  1   100
```

5 rows :

```
1   SIMPLE  cmd     ALL                 134331  100 Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  l       ALL PRIMARY             5   100 Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

I've read somewhere (can't find where anymore :/) that MySQL can choose to not use a primary if there is too few rows in a table (here the limit seems to be 5). Is there a way to disable this ? Because with the index the query takes 80ms, vs 4s without index :/

I'm using MySQL 5.7.9

Thanks

---

Here the 2 tables, simplified.

**EDIT** :

```
CREATE TABLE `liv` (
  `liv_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `liv_nom` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `liv_denomination` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `liv_public` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `liv_slug` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `liv_ordre` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '99',
  `liv_id_crm` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`liv_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

create table cmd
(
    cmd_id int(10) unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    str_id int(10) unsigned null,
    con_id int(10) unsigned null,
    pri_id int(10) unsigned not null,
    liv_id int(10) unsigned null,
    ... 20+ more columns with data only ...
    cmd_transaction_id int(10) unsigned null,
    constraint fk_bout_commande_bout_structure1
        foreign key (str_id) references structure (str_id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint fk_crm_commande_crm_contact1
        foreign key (con_id) references contact (con_id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint fk_crm_commande_livre_campagne1
        foreign key (pri_id) references prix (pri_id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint fk_crm_commande_famille_livreur1
        foreign key (liv_id) references liv (liv_id)
            on update cascade,
);

create index fk_bout_commande_bout_structure1_idx
    on crm_commande (str_id);
create index fk_crm_commande_crm_contact1_idx
    on crm_commande (con_id);
create index fk_crm_commande_famille_livreur1_idx
    on crm_commande (liv_id);
```

Comment: It would help to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we don't know what columns are in the PK or secondary indexes!

Comment: What is the `EXPLAIN` when you leave out the 'hint'?

Comment: @RickJames : I have edited my question adding the 2 CREATE TABLE. If I don't use the FORCE INDEX, I got the same result as with 5 rows (possible_keys = PRIMARY and key = NULL)

Comment: typo : no hint, nor USE INDEX nor FORCE INDEX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can force MySQL to use an index with `force index`, [documented here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-scan-avoidance.html).

First, make sure your statistics are up to date.

Then try something like this (untested)

```
SELECT cmd.cmd_date, liv.liv_nom
FROM cmd 
    LEFT JOIN liv force index (primary) ON cmd.liv_id = liv.liv_id
WHERE 1
ORDER BY cmd_date DESC
```

Different [index hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) might work better. Expect different behavior when liv contains only 5 or 6 rows total rather than 5 or 6 matching rows out of thousands or millions of rows.

Comment: Using FORCE INDEX instead of USE INDEX was the anwser. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The performance problem sees to be that it has to read all of `cmd` even though you want only 20 rows.

The solution is to add this composite index on `cmd`:

```
INDEX(cmd_date, liv_id)
```

And remove all index hints (`USE INDEX...`).

Also, `liv` needs some index starting with `liv_id`.  (Perhaps it is the `PRIMARY KEY`?)

Comment: Why cmd_date in the index ? Because it is in the select ? The problem is I have simplified the request, there is actually 4 left joins and 5 more fields in the select.

Comment: Without an index _starting_ with `cmd_date`, the execution _must_ read all of `cmd` into a temp table, then sort it, and only then deliver 20 rows.  If you had a million rows in the table, that would be a lot of work.  With the index, it can find the 20, then stop.  _Much_ faster.  (Your table has only a few rows, so you don't yet experience the difference.  And `EXPLAIN` does not make it clear other than by saying "filesort".)

Comment: Ok, this is because of the ORDER BY ? If I make a LIMIT 20 without any order by, there if no need for such an index ?

Comment: That is correct.  (`LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` may be fast, but not very useful or predictable.)